# Raster to Numpy Array - how to change a default color-scheme of a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, arcpy

I am trying to change the default color scheme of a `matplotlib` plot.

So far I have the following code:

```
import arcpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
import matplotlib.cm 
input_Raster = arcpy.Raster( 'G:\\WetnessIndex' )
arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray( input_Raster )
cm = plt.set_cmap( 'Blues' )
plt.imshow( arr )
plt.title( 'Wetness Index' )
plt.colorbar( orientation = 'vertical' )
plt.show()
```

The line `cm = plt.get_cmap( 'blues' )` doesn't seem to make a difference like I thought it would, based on the matplotlib `color_maps` reference.

Comment: Thanks @ebarr for the answer. I was just going to answer my own question but was beaten to it! I have discovered that my line: cm = plt.get_cmap('blues') should be

Comment: cm = plt.set_cmap('Blues') which I have now updated in my original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the colour scheme you want as an argument to `imshow`.

e.g.

```
im = plt.imshow(arr,cmap="hot")
```

or in your case:

```
plt.imshow(arr,cmap=cm)
```

Alternatively, you can use the `set_cmap` command to set the default `cmap` for the current figure:

```
plt.set_cmap('hot')
plt.imshow(arr)
```

Comment: Yes, the set_cmap method is perfect for what I need, ty. If you think the question is also helpful please vote it up!